# Ggplot showing random spikes in data

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I try and plot my data from the dataframe to the ggplot, the graph has random spikes along the line and I don't know why. I have tried messing around with the ggplot but nothing works so am wondering if my dataframe is not configured correctly.

The data frame has 4 groups of animals with the size of population recorded over 104 weeks:

```
 head(mydata)
  time   group             size
1    0 rabbits               30
2    1 rabbits            31.38
3    2 rabbits      32.82561384
4    3 rabbits 34.3400006020094
5    4 rabbits  35.926471747402
6    5 rabbits 37.5884983951345
```

This is what the ggplot creates when run

[image: bad plot]

```
  ggplot(mydata, aes(x = time, y = size, group= group), main="lotka volterra model plot") +

    geom_line(aes(col = group)) +

  theme(axis.text = element_blank())
```

```
mydata<-structure(list(time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 18L, 29L, 40L, 51L, 
62L, 73L, 84L, 95L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 
60L, 61L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 74L, 
75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 
89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 
102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 18L, 29L, 
40L, 51L, 62L, 73L, 84L, 95L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 
44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 
72L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 85L, 86L, 
87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 18L, 
29L, 40L, 51L, 62L, 73L, 84L, 95L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 42L, 
43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 
57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 
71L, 72L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 85L, 
86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 
100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
18L, 29L, 40L, 51L, 62L, 73L, 84L, 95L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 
56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 
70L, 71L, 72L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 
85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 
99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("0", 
"1", "10", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "2", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
"24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "3", "30", "31", "32", "33", 
"34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "4", "40", "41", "42", "43", 
"44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "5", "50", "51", "52", "53", 
"54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "6", "60", "61", "62", "63", 
"64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "7", "70", "71", "72", "73", 
"74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "8", "80", "81", "82", "83", 
"84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "9", "90", "91", "92", "93", 
"94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("foxes", "rabbits", "sto foxes", "sto rabbits"
), class = "factor"), size = structure(c(172L, 180L, 188L, 196L, 
204L, 216L, 224L, 231L, 237L, 242L, 246L, 253L, 259L, 265L, 271L, 
275L, 281L, 285L, 291L, 297L, 303L, 309L, 313L, 320L, 324L, 330L, 
337L, 5L, 10L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 40L, 48L, 54L, 62L, 68L, 77L, 
86L, 92L, 98L, 100L, 103L, 106L, 111L, 114L, 144L, 154L, 162L, 
170L, 184L, 191L, 199L, 208L, 218L, 226L, 232L, 238L, 243L, 248L, 
254L, 260L, 266L, 272L, 276L, 282L, 288L, 292L, 298L, 304L, 310L, 
315L, 321L, 325L, 328L, 335L, 2L, 6L, 14L, 19L, 24L, 30L, 34L, 
39L, 44L, 49L, 53L, 57L, 64L, 66L, 71L, 74L, 79L, 82L, 83L, 81L, 
78L, 72L, 65L, 59L, 50L, 42L, 28L, 15L, 227L, 223L, 221L, 220L, 
215L, 211L, 210L, 203L, 202L, 197L, 194L, 192L, 189L, 186L, 183L, 
181L, 179L, 174L, 173L, 168L, 167L, 165L, 161L, 159L, 157L, 153L, 
151L, 149L, 143L, 141L, 139L, 138L, 134L, 132L, 130L, 129L, 127L, 
125L, 123L, 121L, 119L, 117L, 116L, 118L, 120L, 122L, 124L, 126L, 
128L, 131L, 133L, 137L, 140L, 142L, 150L, 152L, 158L, 160L, 166L, 
169L, 175L, 182L, 187L, 193L, 198L, 205L, 214L, 222L, 228L, 235L, 
241L, 247L, 256L, 263L, 270L, 278L, 284L, 294L, 305L, 317L, 323L, 
334L, 9L, 22L, 37L, 51L, 69L, 88L, 102L, 110L, 147L, 177L, 207L, 
229L, 245L, 264L, 280L, 299L, 318L, 331L, 11L, 26L, 43L, 58L, 
75L, 172L, 178L, 185L, 195L, 201L, 213L, 219L, 227L, 234L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 249L, 252L, 255L, 255L, 261L, 269L, 277L, 283L, 287L, 
293L, 300L, 302L, 306L, 311L, 312L, 316L, 322L, 329L, 333L, 332L, 
1L, 4L, 8L, 12L, 18L, 23L, 29L, 36L, 38L, 47L, 55L, 61L, 70L, 
84L, 90L, 97L, 101L, 104L, 105L, 109L, 112L, 135L, 145L, 155L, 
163L, 176L, 190L, 200L, 212L, 217L, 225L, 233L, 239L, 244L, 250L, 
257L, 262L, 267L, 274L, 279L, 286L, 290L, 295L, 301L, 307L, 314L, 
319L, 326L, 327L, 336L, 3L, 7L, 16L, 20L, 25L, 31L, 35L, 41L, 
45L, 52L, 56L, 63L, 67L, 73L, 80L, 85L, 87L, 89L, 94L, 93L, 96L, 
95L, 91L, 227L, 213L, 209L, 195L, 185L, 178L, 178L, 172L, 172L, 
164L, 164L, 164L, 164L, 164L, 164L, 156L, 148L, 136L, 136L, 136L, 
136L, 115L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 107L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
148L, 136L, 115L, 113L, 115L, 113L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 113L, 113L, 148L, 148L, 148L, 
148L, 115L, 115L, 113L, 115L, 136L, 115L, 113L, 115L, 115L, 136L, 
148L, 148L, 136L, 115L, 115L, 156L, 156L, 172L, 172L, 156L, 172L, 
185L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 209L, 219L, 236L, 240L, 258L, 273L, 
287L, 296L, 312L, 333L, 13L, 32L, 46L, 60L, 76L, 99L, 108L, 146L, 
171L, 206L, 230L, 251L, 268L, 289L, 308L), .Label = c("100", 
"1012.93841736696", "1015", "102", "102.906562962176", "1056.50381985743", 
"1064", "107", "107.681565975074", "107.772405683259", "1077.18555087758", 
"109", "110", "1101.34248052638", "1106.71937713192", "1113", 
"112.871167258684", "113", "1147.37104021294", "1159", "118.213953337458", 
"118.907362834956", "119", "1194.47454549496", "1202", "1222.35700531209", 
"123.812386226114", "1234.46815782699", "124", "1242.49940630328", 
"1246", "125", "129.678627213148", "1291.24494843906", "1299", 
"130", "131.883068737542", "133", "1340.45334270173", "135.825399632334", 
"1352", "1353.01585096407", "1376.1737200094", "1389.79769980332", 
"1399", "141", "142", "142.266012655376", "1438.86816034509", 
"1458.3616245406", "146.923717396291", "1466", "1487.15590421503", 
"149.014385797496", "150", "1506", "1534.03518691436", "1534.8487312945", 
"1547.69218094539", "155", "156", "156.085074111268", "1569", 
"1578.74382847183", "1619.48179996562", "1620.36309674333", "1628", 
"163.493294034224", "164.404667496757", "165", "1657.79871894128", 
"1673.39048203113", "1688", "1689.76590687066", "1693.62394525503", 
"170", "171.254949844073", "1710.03514245751", "1714.7828566833", 
"1720", "1730.71178397753", "1731.17917390182", "1737.12790025705", 
"176", "1780", "179.386660661569", "1825", "184.772238294142", 
"1846", "185", "1859", "187.905787924644", "1882", "1885", "1889", 
"1905", "193", "196.830463238049", "199", "206.179616479748", 
"208", "208.555306039675", "215.973004018167", "217", "221", 
"226.231236862199", "23", "231", "232", "236.377317707137", "236.975808527841", 
"239", "24", "248.229122360228", "25", "25.006996053829", "25.014924626149", 
"25.0224494183214", "25.045214840124", "25.0624177868317", "25.0969480307356", 
"25.1281596085623", "25.1692973020694", "25.2210730103966", "25.261518785926", 
"25.3427120320241", "25.3729438809371", "25.4948050967564", "25.502972351872", 
"25.6510661849217", "25.6792760646671", "25.8167441085175", "25.8982682744573", 
"25.9995767010671", "253", "26", "26.1541720515152", "26.1991820171385", 
"26.4152216723683", "26.4496562442932", "26.6473973349067", "26.7877044521904", 
"26.8954475777233", "260.014517996404", "265", "266", "268.967694505081", 
"27", "27.1591450517314", "27.1716567290231", "27.4382939445755", 
"27.6052576910814", "27.7327276941622", "272.356296590851", "278", 
"28", "28.0423069297069", "28.0927121328395", "28.3669176162769", 
"28.6387494628908", "28.706469381617", "285.279744350548", "288", 
"29", "29.060894006489", "29.2486985253466", "29.4301440619011", 
"29.814191678482", "29.9285746772517", "298.811153836992", "299", 
"30", "30.2130274348995", "30.6266593536767", "30.6851813622098", 
"305", "307.170873254196", "31", "31.0551119940305", "31.38", 
"31.4984256324846", "31.5262288687559", "31.956655522999", "312.977842386294", 
"32", "32.4298712292389", "32.4604735067685", "32.82561384", 
"32.9181560223779", "326", "327.808166871801", "33.4216063385245", 
"33.4978810982094", "33.9403312904656", "34", "34.3400006020094", 
"34.4744522289701", "34.6498194865811", "343.331533882608", "346", 
"35", "35.0241023493733", "35.589426339596", "35.926471747402", 
"35.929285755777", "351", "351.950203806801", "359.578404210861", 
"36", "36.170580066137", "36.767730294917", "364", "37", "37.3511750540819", 
"37.3810544441627", "37.5884983951345", "373", "376.580290324766", 
"38", "38.0107403667906", "38.65698616", "38.932599392745", "39.32", 
"39.3297189377729", "393", "394.369745245424", "40", "40.6932665915451", 
"404.382545261556", "408", "41.1539470098798", "412.980340934988", 
"414", "42", "42.6559317498839", "43", "43.0651798238046", "432.446633930023", 
"434", "44", "44.8469363200958", "45.0676068884105", "452.804115504112", 
"456", "465.637719971972", "47.1656191267561", "47.2968531559251", 
"474.089143100815", "48", "482", "486", "49", "49.3638184092258", 
"496.338849122065", "50", "50.0412599281857", "503", "51", "51.6670275190631", 
"519.591022362781", "52", "529", "53.1216681850227", "536.935197912393", 
"54.0803005677077", "543.883956419344", "555", "556", "56", "56.5866412461102", 
"56.6089338777482", "569.256258229975", "58", "580", "59.2584773516901", 
"595.746608482546", "60", "60.4931412285751", "606", "619.469005246511", 
"62.0347463450789", "623.393463893253", "63", "64.9081539728981", 
"64.9438340628061", "640", "65", "652.234689248171", "662", "664", 
"67.9921244976501", "682.307104523925", "69", "69.9106506029712", 
"700", "71", "71.1863059302521", "713.645929259951", "714.291855860478", 
"72", "735", "74", "74.533385009776", "746.284102517739", "75.5939559687986", 
"76", "770", "774", "78.0407014344389", "780.251452081395", "79", 
"81", "81.715943250903", "811", "815.573680850085", "82", "82.0686071733396", 
"822.15243629253", "849", "85.5671627911559", "852.271131437189", 
"88", "89.4657993696359", "89.6027932649582", "890.35728158426", 
"891", "927", "929.836912856086", "93", "93.8316660251566", "943.287593733742", 
"95", "96", "97.9415301108653", "970.703882929996", "979", "98.2630285221179"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-420L))
```

Comment: your y-variable has been imported as a factor rather than a number. Probably because of non-numeric data in the column. you can fix this by converting the column to a character with as.character() and then to a number with as.numeric()

Comment: Thanks, I converted both the x and y variables to characters and then back to numeric and that has fixed the issue.